# How do you filter out data in the first group based data in the second group in dplyr and/or tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame (df) that includes the following columns: horse names, ages and speed figures (value). Initially, I plot the data with ggplot geom_boxplot to see the average speed figure value by age.

Now I would like to do the same plot, but this time only include horses that have raced more than three times as a two-year-old, but I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish this.

I tried to group_by(horse, age), then summarise the nummber of times each horse raced at each age, and finally filter out horses that at 2 years has an n < 4.  Unfortunately, I think my logic/approach may be flawed.

Can anyone think of an elegant way of accomplishing this. It seems straightforward, yet I struggle.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(brew)
#> Warning: package 'brew' was built under R version 4.0.3

df <- tibble(horse=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d"),
             age = c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,2,2,3,3,3,4,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,2,3,3,3,3,4),
             value = c(20,21,19,23,20,17,16,23,24,14,23,24,18,19,16,19,17,24,19,18,17,15,18,12,12,14,15,11,23,24,14,23,24,18))


df
#> # A tibble: 34 x 3
#>    horse   age value
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a         2    20
#>  2 a         2    21
#>  3 a         2    19
#>  4 a         2    23
#>  5 a         2    20
#>  6 a         3    17
#>  7 a         3    16
#>  8 a         3    23
#>  9 a         4    24
#> 10 a         4    14
#> # ... with 24 more rows



df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(age), y=value, fill=as.factor(age))) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=8, color="red", fill="red") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "text", col = "black",     # Add text to plot
               vjust = -1.5, aes(label = paste("X:", round(..y.., digits = 1)))) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
#> Warning: `fun.y` is deprecated. Use `fun` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of ways to keep the horses in the data that have raced more than 3 times as 2 year old.

1. Using `filter` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(horse) %>%
  filter(sum(age == 2) > 3) %>%
  ungroup

#   horse   age value
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         2    20
# 2 a         2    21
# 3 a         2    19
# 4 a         2    23
# 5 a         2    20
# 6 a         3    17
# 7 a         3    16
# 8 a         3    23
# 9 a         4    24
#10 a         4    14
# … with 12 more rows
```

2. Using join

```
df %>%
  filter(age == 2) %>%
  count(horse) %>%
  filter(n > 3) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'horse')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you are aiming for correctly, the following should work.

Here I assume you want to keep all observations for those horses that races at least 3 races when they were 2 years old, that is, keep also the races before and after as well and not only those observations when they were 2 years old.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(horse=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d","d"),
             age = c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,2,2,3,3,3,4,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,2,3,3,3,3,4),
             value = c(20,21,19,23,20,17,16,23,24,14,23,24,18,19,16,19,17,24,19,18,17,15,18,12,12,14,15,11,23,24,14,23,24,18))

df %>% group_by(horse, age) %>% 
  mutate(n_races_by_age = n(),         
         check_if_keep = if_else(age == 2 & n_races_by_age >= 3, 1, 0)) %>% 
  ungroup(age) %>% 
  mutate(
    horse_to_keep = max(check_if_keep)
    # it is still grouped by horse, so keep all observations of those horses for 
    # which the above conditions are met. 
  )
#> # A tibble: 34 x 6
#> # Groups:   horse [4]
#>    horse   age value n_races_by_age check_if_keep horse_to_keep
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>          <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 a         2    20              5             1             1
#>  2 a         2    21              5             1             1
#>  3 a         2    19              5             1             1
#>  4 a         2    23              5             1             1
#>  5 a         2    20              5             1             1
#>  6 a         3    17              3             0             1
#>  7 a         3    16              3             0             1
#>  8 a         3    23              3             0             1
#>  9 a         4    24              2             0             1
#> 10 a         4    14              2             0             1
#> # … with 24 more rows
```

If that is what you mean, then you would only need to add `%>% filter(horse_to_keep==1)` to achieve the desired results.